# Как получить в 1 массив значения из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, symfony

Всем привет подскажите как получить все значения из массива? party_day_from

Обращаюсь сейчас так, но без результатно..
$this->party[0]['party_day_from']

```html
Json.php on line 70:
Date^ {#535 ▼
  -party: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => "1"
      "name" => "Корпоратив"
      "party_day_from" => "2019-01-25"
      "party_day_before" => "2019-01-27"
      "party_time_from" => "12:00:00"
      "party_time_before" => "20:00:00"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => "2"
      "name" => "Др Компании"
      "party_day_from" => "2019-01-21"
      "party_day_before" => "2019-01-23"
      "party_time_from" => "16:00:00"
      "party_time_before" => "21:00:00"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Раньше пользовался Laravel пользовался pluck
$allDate = Arr::pluck($allParties, 'party_day_from');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_column($Date['party'], 'party_day_from');
```

Вот есть функция https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php Не надо городить костыли.

Answer (score 1):

Так выглядит массив по человечески

```
$Date=array("party"=>array(
    "0" => array(
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "Корпоратив",
      "party_day_from" => "2019-01-25",
      "party_day_before" => "2019-01-27",
      "party_time_from" => "12:00:00",
      "party_time_before" => "20:00:00"
    ),
    "1" => array("id" => "2",
      "name" => "Др Компании",
      "party_day_from" => "2019-01-21",
      "party_day_before" => "2019-01-23",
      "party_time_from" => "16:00:00",
      "party_time_before" => "21:00:00"
    )
  )
);


print_r($Date['party'][0]['party_day_from']);
```

и на будующее сразу

```
$rows=count($Date['party']);
for ($tr=0; $tr<$rows; $tr++){print_r($Date['party'][$tr]['party_day_from']); }
```

Comment: возможно тогда так $this->Date['party'][0]['party_day_from']

Comment: Ну и зачем такой костыль?